# How to implement image masking

Tags: iphone

IN scrolllview there is one image with zooming facility.And behind the scrollview there is round image.now i want to masking.I have tried but not working.Can anybudy give me advice.

Comment: Please add source code to your question, so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically masks go in front of the image you are trying to reshape.